# Prevent bootstrap parent also collapsing the a child collapse?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

At the moment, I have two buttons. The parent button when clicked displays stuff and a part of that stuff is another button which too can be clicked to uncollapse.

I want the child to be closed when the parent is opened, however I assume there is a conflict and the child is opening due to the parent.
Is there any way I can address both the parent & child collapsible individually?

Parent:

```html
<button id="smxs-filter-button" type="button" class="smxs-filter-button btn btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#smxs-filter">

<button id='seemore-button' type='button' class='btn btn-block' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#seemore'>
</button>

</button>
```

EDIT:
Here is an example of the issue I have.
I require the secondary collapsible to be CLOSED when the parent is opened so that "yoyo" does not show.
http://www.bootply.com/UhUtCNMRb4

Comment: Try to recreate this issue using Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/ Code Snippets don't have bootstrap included, so they don't do anything currently. Plus, there isn't enough information to discern the problem.

Comment: Done! http://www.bootply.com/UhUtCNMRb4

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
http://www.bootply.com/S9CeJ5zFOn

```html
<div>
  <button id="smxs-filter-button" type="button" class="smxs-filter-button btn btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#smxs-filter">
    <h3>Parent</h3>
  </button>
  
    <div id="smxs-filter" class="smxs-filter panel-collapse collapse">
        <button id="seemore-button" type="button" class="btn btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#seemore">
         <h3>Child</h3>
       </button>
    </div>
  
    <div id="seemore" class="collapse">
     yoyo
    </div>
</div>
```